# Struggling to prove the statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[the original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cJ3k.png)

\[\text{Define functions } f \text{ and } g \text{ as follows:}\]
  \[f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor\]
  \[g(x) = x - \lceil x \rceil  \]
\[\text{If } x \in \mathbb{R}\text{, then } \vert f(x) \vert = \vert\ g(x) \vert \]

I hypothesize that the question wants me to prove "for all x in the domain of Real number, absolute of f(x) is equal to absolute of g(x)". Though I am not sure about that so perhaps someone else has another idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Not clear what the question is.

Comment: The two functions are... the same?

Comment: Calculate $f(1/3)$ and $g(1/3)$.

Comment: isnt this statement false?

Answer (score 1):

You have given two identical functions, therefore, f(x)=g(x) for all x which implies
|f(x)|=|g(x)| for all values of x.
If, you have copied the question incorrectly, do make sure to upload the correct one.

Comment: They are *not* identical.  The first is $x$ minus the floor of $x$ and the second is $x$ minus the ceiling of $x$.  If $n < x < n+1$ for the integer $n$ then $f(x) = x - n$ and $g(x) =x- (n+1)$.  They are not equal.  But $|f(x)| = x-n$ and $|g(x)|=(n+1) -x$ and those are *not* equal so the question is wrong.

Comment: Thats an oops from me :P, excuse my poor eyesight, i read both as the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like f(x) is the (negative) amount rounded up, and g(x) is the amount rounded down, to the next highest and lowest integers respectively.

The equation ${|f(x)| = |g(x)|}$ is not true for all ${x \in \Bbb R}$.  If x=1.3, f(x)=-0.7 and g(x)= 0.3.

If the question is to solve (rather than prove) the equation, then ${x = z}$ or ${ z+0.5 : z \in \Bbb Z}$ would do it, I think.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb Z$ will give you $f(x) =g(x) = 0$.  And $x = z+0.5; z\in \mathbb Z$ will give you $f(x) = 0.5$ and $g(x) =-0.5$.  A bit more work will tell you that in any *other* case $|f(x)| = 1-|g(x)|$

Comment: @fleablood Yes, your answer is much better. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an number there is an integer $n$ so that $n \le x < n+1$.  That integer is $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

And there is an integer $m$ so that $m-1 < x \le m$.  That integer is $\lceil x \rceil$

So $f(x) = x - \lfloor x\rfloor= x - n$ and $0 \le f(x) < 1$.

And $g(x) = x- \lceil x \rceil = x-m$ and $-1 < g(x) \le 0$.

Now $|f(x)| = x- n$ and $|g(x)| = |x-m| = m-x$.

These are *not* equal.  For example of $x = 9.73$ then $f(x) = 9.73 - 9 = 0.73$.  And $g(x) = 9.73-10 = -.27$.

Instead what *is* true is if $x\not \in \mathbb Z$ then $|g(x)| + |f(x)| = 1$.

And if $x \in \mathbb Z$ then $x = \lceil x \rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $f(x) = g(x) = 0$.